# HTML Google chart is not drawing line graph with imported data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database, google-visualization

Hoping to get a bit of help with a project. I have data being written to a Google Firebase Database from sensors. My job is to take this data and display it as a graph on a website. I am successfully importing the data using the following app.js code (variable names are temporary for testing purposes):

> var measurement = []; var date = []; var i;
>
> db.collection('cafes').get().then((snapshot) => {
>   snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
>       for(i=0; i<50; i++) {
>         measurement[i] = doc.data().name;
>         date[i] = doc.data().city;
>       }   })   })

This pulls in each document in the Firebase as needed. Now I come to my problem. I use the following code to try and create a graph from this array of data:

> var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
>   data.addColumn('number', 'date'); data.addColumn('number', 'value');
>
> function drawChartC() {   var data =
>   google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
>       ['Date', 'co2level'],
>       [date[0],  measurement[0]],
>       [date[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AF3b.png),  measurement[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AF3b.png)],
>       [date[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GexB.png),  measurement[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GexB.png)],
>       [date[3],  measurement[3]], ]);
>
> var options = {
>       title: 'Co2 measurements',
>       curveType: 'function',
>       legend: { position: 'bottom' }   };
>
> var chart = new
>   google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
>
> chart.draw(data, options); }
>
> $('#graph').click(function(){
>        });

But it doesn't display properly or create a line. I can't figure out why (pic below).
[image: Unsuccessful Graph]

I have another graph with local data for testing purposes, which does display properly (pic below):

> function drawChartp() {   var data =
>   google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
>       ['Date', 'pmlevel'],
>       ['22/01',  34],
>       ['23/01',  20],
>       ['24/01',  36],
>       ['25/01',  34]   ]);
>
> var options = {
>       title: 'pm measurements',
>       curveType: 'function',
>       legend: { position: 'bottom' }   };
>
> var chart = new
>   google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
>
> chart.draw(data, options); }
>
> $('#graph').click(function(){
>        });

[image: Successful Graph]

any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been trying to figure out this problem for a while. Thank you

Comment: Are you drawing after the `then` from `db.collection('cafes').get()` return?

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated what data is currently in the Firebase. The way I'm pulling it in, it looks like this: [1, 36]
[2, 42]
[3, 35]
[4, 43]

Comment: Yeah my app.js is in the same order as this post. data retrieval, co2 graph, pm graph

Comment: You need to plot inside the `then`: `then((snapshot) => {
Grab data; Plot; })`